# When do companies named "(The) X Company" take the definite article?

Tags: definite-articles, names

I work for a company called "x company" where x is a noun that represents our key product- something like book, computer or hamburger.

I've been advised to refer to it as *the* "x company" in job interviews by my partner, as it makes more grammatical sense, but no one at the company does this. Should it be referred to with a *the*?

Answer (score 1):

It varies from company to company. Unless the company name is customarily used with *the*, you don't have to add the article. For better-known companies, looking at both an official website and conducting a general web search will demonstrate whether others tend to add *the* or not.

Examples:

- *Ford Motor Company* - no article; often abbreviated to *Ford*
- *Bose Corporation* - no article; often abbreviated to *Bose*
- *Hudson's Bay Company* - article optional (*The Hudson's Bay Company*); some sources use it ([Canadian Geographic](https://www.canadiangeographic.ca/article/untold-story-hudsons-bay-company)), others don't ([official site](https://www.hbc.com/)); abbreviated to HBC
- *The Walt Disney Company* - article used ([official site](https://thewaltdisneycompany.com/)); abbreviated to Disney

Comment: I think (and this is a guess, of course, since the OP doesn't give many details) that the OP is asking about names like "Paper Company" or "Telephone Company". They say that "x is a noun", so I read that as meaning the actual company's name is "Noun Company". If you're working for "Evil Corp.", do you say *I work at Evil Corp* or _I work at the Evil Corp."? I doubt we can answer without knowing the specific name though.

Comment: There might be general rules although I can't think of many. No article seems much more common. There are some historical examples like The East India Company which aren't really relevant; maybe "The" is used to sound old/long-established; in contrast dropping the article can sound minimalist and cool.

Comment: @terdon is correct. The company is called something like "telephone company" so my partner thinks I come across badly in interviews when I say I work at telephone company, rather than I work at the telephone company.